# How to ENABLE the web browser's default context menu on right-click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, contextmenu, right-click

I am using a jQuery plugin for a grid widget, and right-clicking anywhere in the widget does not make the browser's default context-menu appear. I would like to add my own event handler on the page to *re*enable that menu. Every topic I found online is asking how to disable the context menu, but I'm trying to do the opposite.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: nope. re-enabling it will require triggering an event on the element you want it to target, and that event would have to bubble up to the document. the grid is stopping it from bubbling, so the only way to fix it is to make the grid stop stopping it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, other than removing the grid's event handler that is preventing context menus.

If you do not remove that event handler, nothing you can do will cause a context menu to open inside the grid because the event has to bubble up to the document for its default action (the opening of a context menu) to occur.